# cannot make an indented new paragraph

Tags: indentation

I basically cannot go to a new indented paragraph in LaTeX. I'm writing in WinEdt and when I leave en empty line between two paragraphs, it also generates an empty line at the output. But I don't want an empty line between the two, I want an indented text.

I used to use `\\` but some colleagues told me to avoid this. So how does LaTeX automatically make a new indented paragraph?

Edit: I copy the code here.

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrbook}

\begin{document}
I basically cannot go to a new indented paragraph in LaTeX. I'm writing in       WinEdt and when I leave en empty line between two paragraphs, it also generates an empty line at the output. But I don't want an empty line between the two, I want an indented text.

I used to use this but some colleagues told me to avoid this. So how does   LaTeX automatically make a new indented paragraph
\end{document}
```

Comment: Indented paragraphs are the default. What did you do to change it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your document probably has some reference to the `parskip` package or is setting `\parskip` in some other way. Without seeing a minimal example of code it's difficult to say more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
\documentclass[parskip=off]{scrbook}
```

Comment: I think he is already doing that: _I leave en empty line between two paragraphs_.

Comment: I use at least one empty line between paragraphs, but at the output it also puts an empty line.

Comment: If there is also an empty line in the output, then you load the package `parskip`, or set the length `\parskip` in the preamble or the option `parskip` if using a KOMA-Script class. None of these schould be present in your document.

Comment: but then the problem is we never can make an empty line between paragraphs, can we?

Comment: You can: `\bigskip` is for one line, `\medskip` a half line.

Comment: would it be possible to remove indention on first paragraphs ?

Comment: after `\section` and others the first one is not idented.  Without it you can use `\noindent blah blah`